# Как авторизироваться на сайте при помощи requests?

Tags: python, requests

Осваиваю requests и такая проблема, я не могу совершить авторизацию по запросам.
Пробовал все и думаю, что ошибка в каком либо токене или куках, но я не уверен.

```
  datas = {
    'login': '*****',
    'password': '*******',
    'remember': '1',
    '_xfRedirect': 'https://samp-rp.online/',
    '_xfToken': '1663692225,d9b21661756539a44c0ea14f440eb81d'
```

}

```
headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    #'cookie': 'ym_uid=166***2501103176***366; _ym_d=***3602501; _ga=GA1.2.1418784802.16***02502; _gid=GA1.2.418***60.1663602502; xf_csrf=frmhz6***esByguQ; xf_user=1004248%2Cxfgv***8SCO1WGNwdOUZM5emT9LC***0qBkdvPk; xf_session=wnoF6R-9JfajSQNXFcPkaj1hQ****S; _gat_gtag_UA_110375725_1=1; _ym_isad=2'
}

res =  requests.post('https://samp-rp.online/login/login',headers=headers,data=datas)
```

Дату я взял уже с верно выполненного запроса

При выполнении кода выше(без использования куки в headers - статус запроса 400 с куками сразу переходя на главную стр сайта все все работает),но мне нужно выполнить авторизацию и уже после получить куки.

https://samp-rp.online/ - гл станица
https://samp-rp.online/login/login - авторизация (еще проблема что статус кода post запроса =303,как я понял это редирект)и возможно ошибка в этом

Comment: Создать сессию, GET-запрос на https://samp-rp.online/login/login, выудить  '_xfToken', POST-запрос на  https://samp-rp.online/login/login с data

Comment: а как выудить токен?

Comment: На пример с помощью BeautifulSoup

Comment: Спасибо вам большое ! Все получилось